# How to crop away convexity defects?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, contour, convexity-defects

I'm trying to detect and fine-locate some objects in images from contours. The contours that I get often include some noise (maybe form the background, I don't know). The objects should look similar to rectangles or squares like:

[image]

I get very good results with shape matching (`cv::matchShapes`) to detect contours with those objects in them, with and without noise, but I have problems with the fine-location in case of noise.

Noise looks like:

[image] or [image] for example.

My idea was to find convexity defects and if they become too strong, somehow crop away the part that leads to concavity. Detecting the defects is ok, typically I get two defects per "unwanted structure", but I'm stuck on how to decide what and where I should remove points from the contours.

Here are some contours, their masks (so you can extract the contours easily) and the convex hull including thresholded convexity defects:

[image][image][image]

[image][image][image]

[image][image][image]

[image][image][image]

[image][image][image]

[image][image][image]

[image][image][image]

[image][image][image]

[image][image][image]

Could I just walk through the contour and locally decide whether a "left turn" is performed by the contour (if walking clockwise) and if so, remove contour points until the next left turn is taken? Maybe starting at a convexity defect?

I'm looking for algorithms or code, programming language should not be important, algorithm is more important.

Comment: Have you looked at `convexityDefects`? http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#convexitydefects

Comment: @zeFrenchy yes, the red dots in the convex-hull images are from thresholded convexityDefects' result. I just can't think of an algorithm on how to go on from there.

Comment: Got you, never used it but I just dropped that in there just in case :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This approach works only on points. You don't need to create masks for this.

The main idea is:

1. Find defects on contour
2. If I find at least two defects, find the two closest defects
3. Remove from the contour the points between the two closest defects
4. Restart from 1 on the new contour

I get the following results. As you can see, it has some drawbacks for *smooth* defects (e.g. 7th image), but works pretty good for clearly visible defects. I don't know if this will solve your problem, but can be a starting point. In practice should be quite fast (you can surely optimize the code below, specially the `removeFromContour` function). Also, the only parameter of this approach is the amount of the convexity defect, so it works well with both small and big defecting blobs.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int ed2(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs)
{
    return (lhs.x - rhs.x)*(lhs.x - rhs.x) + (lhs.y - rhs.y)*(lhs.y - rhs.y);
}

vector<Point> removeFromContour(const vector<Point>& contour, const vector<int>& defectsIdx)
{
    int minDist = INT_MAX;
    int startIdx;
    int endIdx;

    // Find nearest defects
    for (int i = 0; i < defectsIdx.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < defectsIdx.size(); ++j)
        {
            float dist = ed2(contour[defectsIdx[i]], contour[defectsIdx[j]]);
            if (minDist > dist)
            {
                minDist = dist;
                startIdx = defectsIdx[i];
                endIdx = defectsIdx[j];
            }
        }
    }

    // Check if intervals are swapped
    if (startIdx <= endIdx)
    {
        int len1 = endIdx - startIdx;
        int len2 = contour.size() - endIdx + startIdx;
        if (len2 < len1)
        {
            swap(startIdx, endIdx);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int len1 = startIdx - endIdx;
        int len2 = contour.size() - startIdx + endIdx;
        if (len1 < len2)
        {
            swap(startIdx, endIdx);
        }
    }

    // Remove unwanted points
    vector<Point> out;
    if (startIdx <= endIdx)
    {
        out.insert(out.end(), contour.begin(), contour.begin() + startIdx);
        out.insert(out.end(), contour.begin() + endIdx, contour.end());
    } 
    else
    {
        out.insert(out.end(), contour.begin() + endIdx, contour.begin() + startIdx);
    }

    return out;
}

int main()
{
    Mat1b img = imread("path_to_mask", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    Mat3b out;
    cvtColor(img, out, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    findContours(img.clone(), contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    vector<Point> pts = contours[0];

    vector<int> hullIdx;
    convexHull(pts, hullIdx, false);

    vector<Vec4i> defects;
    convexityDefects(pts, hullIdx, defects);

    while (true)
    {
        // For debug
        Mat3b dbg;
        cvtColor(img, dbg, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

        vector<vector<Point>> tmp = {pts};
        drawContours(dbg, tmp, 0, Scalar(255, 127, 0));

        vector<int> defectsIdx;
        for (const Vec4i& v : defects)
        {
            float depth = float(v[3]) / 256.f;
            if (depth > 2) //  filter defects by depth
            {
                // Defect found
                defectsIdx.push_back(v[2]);

                int startidx = v[0]; Point ptStart(pts[startidx]);
                int endidx = v[1]; Point ptEnd(pts[endidx]);
                int faridx = v[2]; Point ptFar(pts[faridx]);

                line(dbg, ptStart, ptEnd, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 1);
                line(dbg, ptStart, ptFar, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1);
                line(dbg, ptEnd, ptFar, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1);
                circle(dbg, ptFar, 4, Scalar(127, 127, 255), 2);
            }
        }

        if (defectsIdx.size() < 2)
        {
            break;
        }

        // If I have more than two defects, remove the points between the two nearest defects
        pts = removeFromContour(pts, defectsIdx);
        convexHull(pts, hullIdx, false);
        convexityDefects(pts, hullIdx, defects);
    }


    // Draw result contour
    vector<vector<Point>> tmp = { pts };
    drawContours(out, tmp, 0, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1);

    imshow("Result", out);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Working on an approximated contour (e.g. using `CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` in `findContours`) may be faster, but the length of contours must be computed using `arcLength()`.

This is the snippet to replace in the *swapping* part of `removeFromContour`:

```
// Check if intervals are swapped
if (startIdx <= endIdx)
{
    //int len11 = endIdx - startIdx;
    vector<Point> inside(contour.begin() + startIdx, contour.begin() + endIdx);
    int len1 = (inside.empty()) ? 0 : arcLength(inside, false);

    //int len22 = contour.size() - endIdx + startIdx;
    vector<Point> outside1(contour.begin(), contour.begin() + startIdx);
    vector<Point> outside2(contour.begin() + endIdx, contour.end());
    int len2 = (outside1.empty() ? 0 : arcLength(outside1, false)) + (outside2.empty() ? 0 : arcLength(outside2, false));

    if (len2 < len1)
    {
        swap(startIdx, endIdx);
    }
}
else
{
    //int len1 = startIdx - endIdx;
    vector<Point> inside(contour.begin() + endIdx, contour.begin() + startIdx);
    int len1 = (inside.empty()) ? 0 : arcLength(inside, false);


    //int len2 = contour.size() - startIdx + endIdx;
    vector<Point> outside1(contour.begin(), contour.begin() + endIdx);
    vector<Point> outside2(contour.begin() + startIdx, contour.end());
    int len2 = (outside1.empty() ? 0 : arcLength(outside1, false)) + (outside2.empty() ? 0 : arcLength(outside2, false));

    if (len1 < len2)
    {
        swap(startIdx, endIdx);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Micka Probably with a smarter implementation of the above code, working on an approximated contour (similar to CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE), this may actually be really fast. Please post an answer if you find something that works for your requirements, it can be very helpful :D

Comment: currently the decision whether to swap is made by the index-distance within the contour? That's probably the reason, why for `CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` sometimes the wrong parts are cropped away (wrong direction)? Could arcLength be an appropriate heuristic instead?

Comment: @Micka check update. Now it works as before for me. To compute arc length you need the vector of points: you can probably arrange stuff in a smarter way :D

Comment: currently already fast enough without optimizations and works nearly perfectly for my data, thank you!

Comment: a few things to add: Before calling `convexityDefects` I have to check whether at least 4 points are present in the contour (I just break otherwise). And within `removeFromContour` it can happen, that startIdx == endIdx. I don't know WHY that happens, but I changed the the condition for updating `minDist` to not update for same Idx points and handle that case afterwards (had additionally to `initialize` startIdx and endIdx to test for that case).

Comment: @miki I am trying to translate this code in to python, I don't have much background in C++ specially vector data structure. Can you please explain what is happening in code snippet 1, in function **removeFromContour** lines starts with out.insert(). I tried to look up for the details of **vector** but couldn't find reasonable detail. It would be great if you can explain. Thanks.

Comment: @MuazUsmani: were you succeeded in creating the python verison of it?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a Python implementation following Miki's code.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

def ed2(lhs, rhs):
    return(lhs[0] - rhs[0])*(lhs[0] - rhs[0]) + (lhs[1] - rhs[1])*(lhs[1] - rhs[1])


def remove_from_contour(contour, defectsIdx, tmp):
    minDist = sys.maxsize
    startIdx, endIdx = 0, 0

    for i in range(0,len(defectsIdx)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(defectsIdx)):
            dist = ed2(contour[defectsIdx[i]][0], contour[defectsIdx[j]][0])
            if minDist > dist:
                minDist = dist
                startIdx = defectsIdx[i]
                endIdx = defectsIdx[j]

    if startIdx <= endIdx:
        inside = contour[startIdx:endIdx]
        len1 = 0 if inside.size == 0 else cv2.arcLength(inside, False)
        outside1 = contour[0:startIdx]
        outside2 = contour[endIdx:len(contour)]
        len2 = (0 if outside1.size == 0 else cv2.arcLength(outside1, False)) + (0 if outside2.size == 0 else cv2.arcLength(outside2, False))
        if len2 < len1:
            startIdx,endIdx = endIdx,startIdx     
    else:
        inside = contour[endIdx:startIdx]
        len1 = 0 if inside.size == 0 else cv2.arcLength(inside, False)
        outside1 = contour[0:endIdx]
        outside2 = contour[startIdx:len(contour)]
        len2 = (0 if outside1.size == 0 else cv2.arcLength(outside1, False)) + (0 if outside2.size == 0 else cv2.arcLength(outside2, False))
        if len1 < len2:
            startIdx,endIdx = endIdx,startIdx

    if startIdx <= endIdx:
        out = np.concatenate((contour[0:startIdx], contour[endIdx:len(contour)]), axis=0)
    else:
        out = contour[endIdx:startIdx]
    return out


def remove_defects(mask, debug=False):
    tmp = mask.copy()
    mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # get contour
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(
        mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    assert len(contours) > 0, "No contours found"
    contour = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)[-1] #largest contour
    if debug:
        init = cv2.drawContours(tmp.copy(), [contour], 0, (255, 0, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
        figure, ax = plt.subplots(1)
        ax.imshow(init)
        ax.set_title("Initital Contour")

    hull = cv2.convexHull(contour, returnPoints=False)
    defects = cv2.convexityDefects(contour, hull)

    while True:
        defectsIdx = []
        
        for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
            s, e, f, d = defects[i, 0]
            start = tuple(contour[s][0])
            end = tuple(contour[e][0])
            far = tuple(contour[f][0])
            
            depth = d / 256
            if depth > 2:
                defectsIdx.append(f)

        if len(defectsIdx) < 2:
            break

        contour = remove_from_contour(contour, defectsIdx, tmp)
        hull = cv2.convexHull(contour, returnPoints=False)
        defects = cv2.convexityDefects(contour, hull)

    if debug:
      rslt = cv2.drawContours(tmp.copy(), [contour], 0, (0, 255, 255), 1)
      figure, ax = plt.subplots(1)
      ax.imshow(rslt)
      ax.set_title("Corrected Contour")

mask = cv2.imread("a.png")
remove_defects(mask, True)
```

Answer (score 2):

I came up with the following approach for detecting the bounds of the rectangle/square. It works based on few assumptions: shape is rectangular or square, it is centered in the image, it is not tilted.

- divide the **masked(filled)** image in half along the x-axis so that you get two regions (a top half and a bottom half)
- take the projection of each region on to the x-axis
- take all the non-zero entries of these projections and take their medians. These medians give you the y bounds
- similarly, divide the image in half along y-axis, take the projections on to y-axis, then calculate the medians to get the x bounds
- use the bounds to crop the region

Median line and the projection for a top half of a sample image is shown below.
[image: proj-n-med-line]

Resulting bounds and cropped regions for two samples:
[image: s1]
[image: s2]

The code is in Octave/Matlab, and I tested this on Octave (you need the image package to run this).

```
clear all
close all

im = double(imread('kTouF.png'));
[r, c] = size(im);
% top half
p = sum(im(1:int32(end/2), :), 1);
y1 = -median(p(find(p > 0))) + int32(r/2);
% bottom half
p = sum(im(int32(end/2):end, :), 1);
y2 = median(p(find(p > 0))) + int32(r/2);
% left half
p = sum(im(:, 1:int32(end/2)), 2);
x1 = -median(p(find(p > 0))) + int32(c/2);
% right half
p = sum(im(:, int32(end/2):end), 2);
x2 = median(p(find(p > 0))) + int32(c/2);

% crop the image using the bounds
rect = [x1 y1 x2-x1 y2-y1];
cr = imcrop(im, rect);
im2 = zeros(size(im));
im2(y1:y2, x1:x2) = cr;

figure,
axis equal
subplot(1, 2, 1)
imagesc(im)
hold on
plot([x1 x2 x2 x1 x1], [y1 y1 y2 y2 y1], 'g-')
hold off
subplot(1, 2, 2)
imagesc(im2)
```

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point and assuming the defects are never too big relative to the object you are trying to recognize, you can try a simple erode+dilate strategy before using `cv::matchShapes` as shown below.

```
 int max = 40; // depending on expected object and defect size
 cv::Mat img = cv::imread("example.png");
 cv::Mat eroded, dilated;
 cv::Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(max*2,max*2), cv::Point(max,max));
 cv::erode(img, eroded, element);
 cv::dilate(eroded, dilated, element);
 cv::imshow("original", img);
 cv::imshow("eroded", eroded);
 cv::imshow("dilated", dilated);
```

[image]

Comment: the problem is that the object size can vary, so I can't fix `max`. Do you have any assumptions about how to choose `max` depending on some extractable contour's properties like boundind rectangle, contour area or similar?

Comment: Can you not use a percentage of the maximum dimension of the blob you are currently testing? Just a thought.

Comment: You could also try increasing amount of erosion/dilation until you find what you're looking for or nothing is left from erosion.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to do this with about 100 fps, maybe I can use subsampling though. I'll try to find a property to estimate the erosion size, thx. First results look ok, the "corners" are cropped etc but that won't be a real problem. However I guess/hope there could be a more elegant (and maybe faster) way, working with the contours and the assumption that the object is basically convex.

Comment: Unless the stuff you looking for is moving really fast you might get away with doing this every 10 frame or whatever works. Sub-sampling the images and the timeline may help meeting your real-time constraints.

Comment: On a (final) note: erosion/dilation *must* be faster than detecting contour, then finding convexity defects, then finding a way to deal with those.

Comment: I get those contours as input, To use erision/dilation I have to even draw the mask myself first. Input are just the contour points (which are hard to share on SO, so I posted the drawn images. Not sure about the speed of convexity defect computation, I'll compare in the end.