# How to remove an unwanted extension of a threshold?

Tags: python, opencv

This is the thresholded image in context. The part that is unwanted is the extension on the top, I hope it's deducible. If it isn't, please ask. I want the almost circular part that would remain after removing the extension in context. How do I go about doing it? I've had someone suggest morphologial operation would help. Could someone please expand on that, and maybe provide an example?

Thanks

[image]

Here's another example:

[image]

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35252058/5008845)

Comment: Thanks! That seems helpful. Going through it.

Comment: i think if you share your code and original images you will get better ideas to achieve what you want

Comment: Morphological opening could help with the first example, but not with the second.

Answer (score 5):

The best practice would be, since you only need shapes similar to circle. Try using curve fitting along with Kalman Filter. Hope this would definitely tackle the problem in a more efficient way. circle equation will try to pull(correct) the points towards the center and Kalman will help trace the curve effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is like  a piece of flat plane[3D view of your image](http://perso.univ-lemans.fr/~berger/Afsd56/Video20160430205730.mp4) . OTSU is not always a good idea. Disable it and choose a manual threshold (75).

Answer (score 0):

```
from scipy import misc
from skimage.morphology import erosion    
data = misc.imread('gycl1.jpg')
eroded = erosion(data, disk(25)
```

[image]

Is this what you meant?  I am using the erosion morphological operator with a disk size (to maintain the circular function).