# Get rid of irregularities in image contour found by opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an image with conponets which have most of the parts smooth, but it has some unsmooth parts which are also detected as contour as showed in image. I want to detect and delete them. Anyone has experience about how to do that? thanks!

[image: what I have got from open cv]

[image: part I want to delete]

Comment: If your images always look like this and you're not looking for precise contours but more for a "smooth" shape, you can draw a quadrilateral using the 4 extreme points of each contour (southest-eastest one, southest-westest one, etc)

Comment: Thank you but it's a pity I look for precise contours. I only want to detect and cut these little parts.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35252058/5008845)

Comment: @Miki  Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I mean. I tried the code with some of my sample images and it works sometimes well but sometimes not. I must read the code and make some changes I think.