# Opencv fitellipse draws the wrong contour

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, computer-vision, opencv, python

I want to draw the ellipse contour around the given figure append below. I am not getting the correct result since the figure consist of two lines.

***I have tried the following:-***

1. Read the Image
2. Convert the BGR to HSV
3. Define the Range of color blue
4. Create the inRange Mask to capture the value of between lower and upper blue
5. Find the contour & Draw the fit ellipse.

***Here is the source code-***

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image=cv2.imread('./source image.jpg')

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_blue= np.array([75, 0, 0])
upper_blue= np.array([105, 255, 255])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
res=cv2.bitwise_and(image,image,mask=mask)
_,contours,_=cv2.findContours(close,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(max(contours,key=cv2.contourArea))
cv2.ellipse(image,ellipse,(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('mask',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

***The figure/Image below show the Expected & Actual Output-***

[Expected & Actual display image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOWw0.jpg)

***Source Image***
[Source Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8gx3.jpg)

***Output Contour Array***
[Contour file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bQyx2dkiabBIX7ufCY3D1mU3YQVwo_lp)

Comment: Can you add the source image for us to try with? Also, why are you sorting the contours just to pull a single one out? Use `max()` instead, it can also take a `key` function :)

Comment: Try to visualize mask image and drawContours on it.

Comment: You have the expected and actual result image, which is great, but I meant the input image with neither circle drawn on it.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds  Source/ Input Image added below

Comment: Try to apply cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel) before findContours. And don't use bitwise_and

Comment: @Nuzhny I have used bitwise_and for the general case scenario as if we are dealing with colored concentric ellipses.

Comment: can you upload a contour image? fitEllipse will expect the whole input being an ellipse, just as line fitting will have problems with outliers, ellipse fitting will have, too. Maybe you can use the code of the answer here to prepocess your contour, to get better input data for ellipse fitting? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35226993/how-to-crop-away-convexity-defects

Comment: @Micka Source/Input, Actual and Excepted image with contour are appended below.

Comment: @NuzhnyI have updated the source/input to get a generalized result. Try to run the code with this image

Comment: Note that your current set of code doesn't run; `close` is not defined.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds try with edited code and input image for better interpretation.

Comment: Yes---it doesn't run. There are multiple undefined variables; please copy and paste the code in your post and see :)

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Copy the code again and use the correct Input image path. Then Run the code and check whether it's working or not

Comment: @MayankPratapSingh I have seen the input images, but not the contours (I don't have time to compile/run your code atm, sorry) - the result of bitwise-operation and findContours, drawn on an empty image, or at least the input that you send to findContours. This will give more information about, that kind of input to fitEllipse is presented.

Comment: @Micka Appended contour output file.

Comment: @MayankPratapSingh I'm adding convexHull and update my C++ code with new result

Answer (score -1):

I try to run your code on C++ and add erosion, dilatation and convexHull for result contour:

```
auto DetectEllipse = [](cv::Mat rgbImg, cv::Mat hsvImg, cv::Scalar fromColor, cv::Scalar toColor)
{
    cv::Mat threshImg;
    cv::inRange(hsvImg, fromColor, toColor, threshImg);
    cv::erode(threshImg, threshImg, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3, 3)), cv::Point(-1, -1), 2);
    cv::dilate(threshImg, threshImg, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3, 3)), cv::Point(-1, -1), 2);

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    cv::findContours(threshImg, contours, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    int areaThreshold = (rgbImg.cols * rgbImg.rows) / 100;

    std::vector<cv::Point> allContours;
    allContours.reserve(10 * areaThreshold);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        if (contours[i].size() > 4)
        {
            auto area = cv::contourArea(contours[i]);
            if (area > areaThreshold)
            {
                allContours.insert(allContours.end(), contours[i].begin(), contours[i].end());
            }
        }
    }
    if (allContours.size() > 4)
    {
        std::vector<cv::Point> hull;
        cv::convexHull(allContours, hull, false);

        cv::ellipse(rgbImg, cv::fitEllipse(hull), cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255), 2);
    }
};

cv::Mat rgbImg = cv::imread("h8gx3.jpg", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
cv::Mat hsvImg;
cv::cvtColor(rgbImg, hsvImg, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);

DetectEllipse(rgbImg, hsvImg, cv::Scalar(75, 0, 0), cv::Scalar(105, 255, 255));
DetectEllipse(rgbImg, hsvImg, cv::Scalar(10, 100, 20), cv::Scalar(25, 255, 255));

cv::imshow("rgbImg", rgbImg);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

Result looks correct:
[image]

Comment: what if I want to draw the contours for both ellipses.

Comment: Do you mean an orange ellipse?

Comment: What if the color is not mentioned. And now we have have to draw the contour around the ellipses

Comment: If you know about the main color - it simple. I made the edit for the orange ellipse too

Comment: And if you want to know about all main colors on the picture then create another question

Comment: Thanks for help Nuzhny. I have created another question, check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54687461/opencv-ellipse-contour-not-fitting-correctly?noredirect=1#comment96162925_54687461