# Opencv - Ellipse Contour Not fitting correctly

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

I want to draw contours around the concentric ellipses shown in the image appended below. I am not getting the expected result.

***I have tried the following steps:***

1. Read the Image
2. Convert Image to Grayscale.
3. Apply GaussianBlur
4. Get the Canny edges
5. Draw the ellipse contour

***Here is the Source code:***

```
import cv2

target=cv2.imread('./source image.png')

targetgs = cv2.cvtColor(target,cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)

targetGaussianBlurGreyScale=cv2.GaussianBlur(targetgs,(3,3),0)

canny=cv2.Canny(targetGaussianBlurGreyScale,30,90)


kernel=cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
close=cv2.morphologyEx(canny,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel)


_,contours,_=cv2.findContours(close,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

if len(contours) != 0:
    for c in contours:
        if len(c) >= 50:
            hull=cv2.convexHull(c)
            cv2.ellipse(target,cv2.fitEllipse(hull),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('mask',target)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

***The image below shows the Expected & Actual result:***
[image: Expected & Actual Result Image]

***Source Image:***

[image: Source Image]

Comment: For the next time, please check how to properly format your code blocks (done it for you this time); also, since your issue is with the Python API, please avoid using the `c++` tag (removed).

Comment: @desertnaut thanks for edits man

Answer (score 4):

Algorithm can be simple:

1. Convert RGB to HSV, split and working with a V channel.
2. Threshold for delete all color lines.
3. HoughLinesP for delete non color lines.
4. dilate + erosion for close holes in ellipses.
5. findContours + fitEllipse.

Result:

[image: Result image]

With new image (added black curve) my approach do not works. It seems that you need to use Hough ellipse detection instead "findContours + fitEllipse".
OpenCV don't have implementation but you can find it [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_circular_elliptical_hough_transform.html) or [here](https://github.com/horiken4/ellipse-detection).

If you don't afraid C++ code (for OpenCV library C++ is more expressive) then:

```
cv::Mat rgbImg = cv::imread("sqOOE.jpg", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);

cv::Mat hsvImg;
cv::cvtColor(rgbImg, hsvImg, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);

std::vector<cv::Mat> chans;
cv::split(hsvImg, chans);
cv::threshold(255 - chans[2], chans[2], 200, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

std::vector<cv::Vec4i> linesP;
cv::HoughLinesP(chans[2], linesP, 1, CV_PI/180, 50, chans[2].rows / 4, 10);
for (auto l : linesP)
{
    cv::line(chans[2], cv::Point(l[0], l[1]), cv::Point(l[2], l[3]), cv::Scalar::all(0), 3, cv::LINE_AA);
}
cv::dilate(chans[2], chans[2], cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3, 3)), cv::Point(-1, -1), 4);
cv::erode(chans[2], chans[2], cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3, 3)), cv::Point(-1, -1), 3);

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
cv::findContours(chans[2], contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_TREE, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    if (contours[i].size() > 4)
    {
        cv::ellipse(rgbImg, cv::fitEllipse(contours[i]), cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255), 2);
    }
}

cv::imshow("rgbImg", rgbImg);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

Comment: Thank for help buddy. One last query, I have added the curved line in the source image. Does it work with the current code?

Comment: I'll try. Do you can save image into png format? Jpeg is very bad choice for the graphics

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience, Updated the format of JPG to PNG.

Comment: With any black curve my algorithm don't work. I'm updating my answer - add links to the Hough-based ellipse detectors