# Open CV Contours - Splitting concave polygon into multiple convex ones

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, contour, convex-polygon

I have the below image in a numpy array

[image]

I want to

1. separate the blocks into individual contours or any coordinate representation.
2. I then want to transform any concave polygons into multiple convex polygons.

Like this

[image]

So far I've managed to isolate each block into contours with opencv... but is there an easy way to split the L shape objects into two or more square blocks. The new contours of each shape can overlap if needed.

It may also be the case that I have an Image like this which does not have such straight lines.

[image]

I have used `cv2.approxPolyDP` to draw the shape, but again they are concave and I need them splitting.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is it sure that the 2 objects forming the L shape are of different colours as shown in the image?

Comment: maybe you can adapt: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35226993/how-to-crop-away-convexity-defects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so thanks Rahul for your answer.

I ended up finding a package that helped me trangulate the polygons which solved my issue.

download with :

```
pip install sect
```

Then :

```
from sect.triangulation import constrained_delaunay_triangles
```

Take the contours generated by openCV - this generates them as below.

[image]

Then "smooth" the colours so there are less of them. I've used this

```
epsilon = 0.005 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, epsilon, True)
```

then run it through sect

```
constrained_delaunay_triangles([tuple(x) for x in approx.squeeze()])
```

The output splits the polygons into triangles removing ALL concave polygons totally.

[image]

Comment: Just a question, how exactly is it working after finding triangles because I am seeing the shape been broken into more than required parts.

Comment: My issue was (see point 2) that I couldn't have concave polygons. They're all gone in this example. Thanks for your input though it helped me on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of is, for each contour, find it convex hull first.[See this link](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html#convex-hull)

Now find the defect points between contour and its convex hull. [See this link](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_more_functions/py_contours_more_functions.html#convexity-defects)

Now using the data of defects distance, find the point with maximum distance. This point will be the points where the 2 objects are joined in L shape. Now from this point, draw a perpendicular line to the contour tangent at that point, and again find contours. The resultant contours will be the 2 contours for the L shape.

Note: In this approach, it is possible that some part of one object comes in other while dividing them at the boundary.