Split concave object mask into 1 or more convex sub-sections
I am working with an object detection model.  It works pretty well, but the output is a mask, and I need bounding boxes. Naively, I can just use OpenCV to draw a bounding box around the contours of the mask, but if the mask is very concave that can include large non-image regions.
I've figured out how to use a convex hull to check if the mask is concave, but I can't figure out how to split a concave mask into convex sub-regions.  I'm ok if my bounding boxes overlap, I just don't want them to contain large non-masked regions.
Is there a simple heuristic I can use here to split the bounding boxes into sub-boxes?  Maybe I could use an optimizer to find a set of 1 or more rectangles that mostly fill a given contour?
Here are some examples of my semantic masks:
I'd like to split the big object into 2 or 3 rectangles, but keep the 2 smaller objects as-is:

2 rectangles would be good, but we could get up to 5

2 rectangles would be prefect for the big object, but I'd like to keep the small one as-is:

Here's a quick script to draw the bounding boxes, which illustrates the issue:
import numpy as np
import cv2
import requests
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from io import BytesIO

response = requests.get('https://i.sstatic.net/d771v.png')
image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content)).convert('RGB')
image_array = np.array(image.convert('L'))
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(image_array, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
for contour in contours:
    x1, y1, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    x2 = x1 + w
    y2 = y1 + h
    draw.rectangle([(x1, y1), (x2, y2)], outline="red", width=3)
image.show()

Here's an example of the bounding boxes I have now.  I want to cut off the "arm" of the big object into its own box.


I don't see how you could get five bounding boxes from that second picture. The segmentation masks look spotty, they don't seem to be segmenting the objects effectively, maybe you could correct the model adding more pixel classes at the object's boundaries? It's difficult to tell what's going on without seeing the unprocessed input images, but coming up with a simple heuristic to compensate for a segmentation model seems... troublesome.

2d set cover, partition, ... it's a geometry/computer graphics/discrete math problem. -- why? what's the model and source image? is the object itself non-convex?

@stateMachine The masks are really good!  They cover almost exactly what I want to get.  The problem is turning the masks into rectangular regions.

@ChristophRackwitz 2d set cover, partition, ... it's a geometry/computer graphics/discrete math problem. — yes: I think this is a discrete math problem, I just don't know how to solve it.  The objects are convex.  They're really sets of objects, or regions of the image

so you need instance segmentation, not mere semantic segmentation. we could have helped a lot better without all this secrecy.

have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/35226993/2393191 and the answer. Maybe you can reproduce it in python.

first idea: split image (or region in rectangle) into smaller images (sections) (ie, split into 4 elements) and search in every image (section) contours. And eventually later you could repeat it for every image - split smaller image again in even smaller images. etc.

@ChristophRackwitz yeah— I have a pretrained semantic segmentation model (the layout model from surya ocr) and its almost perfect for my use case.  The problem is, my downstream application needs rectangles, so I am trying to crop the semantic maps from the model into rectangles for my application.  I really don't want to train my own model— I have one that works great, and am just fiddling with the post-processing.

@Micka That answer is hugely helpful, thank you!
